# Django cms migration wrong number (0) of constraints

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, migration, constraints

I've been following the Django CMS installation tutorial, but am stuck when configuring Django CMS to work with Django, here:

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html#configuring-your-project-for-django-cms

When I omit "cms" from the INSTALLED_APPS, the migration succeeds and the default Django page displays in my browser.

However, when I add "cms" to INSTALLED_APS and run "python manage.py migrate", the migration fails as you can see in the code below.

This fails either with an empty database, or running it after the successful migration I mentioned above.

I have altered the order of INSTALLED_APPS but that has no effect.

I've looked at the definition "alter_unique_together" in:

```
site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py
```

but can't make sense of what is failing.

Help appreciated, will provide any extra details required.

## Info

### Project File Structure

- natureschoolssite

  - manage.py
  - media/
  - my.cnf
  - natureschoolssite/

    - models.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - static/
  - templates/

    - base.html
    - template_1.html
    - template_2.html

### Output of "python manage.py migrate"

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: treebeard, sekizai, djangocms_admin_style
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, menus, contenttypes, cms
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cms.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cms.0002_auto_20140816_1918... OK
  Applying cms.0003_auto_20140926_2347... OK
  Applying cms.0004_auto_20140924_1038... OK
  Applying cms.0005_auto_20140924_1039... OK
  Applying cms.0006_auto_20140924_1110... OK
  Applying cms.0007_auto_20141028_1559... OK
  Applying cms.0008_auto_20150208_2149... OK
  Applying cms.0008_auto_20150121_0059...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 282, in database_forwards
    getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/natureschools/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 302, in alter_unique_together
    ", ".join(columns),
ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for cms_page(publisher_is_draft, application_namespace)
```

### Output of "pip freeze"

```
cffi==0.9.2
cmsplugin-filer==0.10.1
cryptography==0.9
Django==1.7.7
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-classy-tags==0.5
django-cms==3.1.0
django-filer==0.9.9
django-mptt==0.6.1
django-polymorphic==0.7.1
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.7
django-treebeard==3.0
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.2
easy-thumbnails==2.2
enum34==1.0.4
html5lib==0.999
idna==1.1
ipaddress==1.0.7
MySQL-python==1.2.5
mysqlclient==1.3.6
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
Pillow==2.8.1
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycparser==2.13
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
six==1.3.0
South==1.0.2
Unidecode==0.4.17
```

### Settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Django settings for natureschoolssite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6x9y_5)$$&$k&so_p5v=if+_4=f!z3%2almz%nha*%*r(vjm#w'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cms',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'treebeard',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware'
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
    'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'natureschoolssite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'natureschoolssite.wsgi.application'


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # The docs say it should be absolute path: BASE_DIR is precisely one.
    # Life is wonderful!
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/var/www/natureschools/natureschoolssite/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en-us', 'English'),
]

TIME_ZONE = 'GMT'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Comment: Have a look at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23906

Comment: Did you find a real solution for that issue ? I'm having exactly the same problem and I can't find a solution. I've posted on Github issues tracker but no luck there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the Zinnia blog app. What I ended up doing was that I simply created the indices the migration wants to delete directly in the Postgres shell:

```
db=> create index on zinnia_entry (slug, creation_date);
CREATE INDEX
db=> create index on zinnia_entry (status, creation_date, start_publication, end_publication);
CREATE INDEX
```

In your case that might be something like:

```
db=> create index on cms_page (publisher_is_draft, application_namespace);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: which is quite a dirty hack though. esp. as it will not work with any test and CI env.